# How to "delete" original linked list when splitting the linked list into odd and even?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is the original code that I used:

```
void split(Node*& in, Node*& odds, Node*& evens)
{
    /* Add code here */
    if (!in) 
    {
        odds = NULL;
        evens = NULL;
        return;
    } 
    else if (in->value % 2 == 1) 
    {
        odds = in;
        return split(in->next, odds->next, evens);
    } 
    else 
    {       
        evens = in;
        return split(in->next, odds, evens->next);
    }
}
```

I need to delete the original linked list while shifting the values to the new ones. And according to the problem I have to use recursion as I did. If I print it right now, then it picks the first node and prints the linked list associated with that node.
For example, for the test code given below, I get

```
18 3 5 6 8 9
18 6 8
3 5 9
18 6 8
```

as the output, while I need this:

```
18 3 5 6 8 9

3 5 9
18 6 8
```

Here is the test code:

```
void printList(Node* n) 
{ 
    while (n != NULL) { 
        cout << n->value << " "; 
        n = n->next; 
    } 
        cout << "\n";
} 

int main()
{
    Node* odds = NULL;
    Node* evens = NULL;
    Node* in = new Node{ 18, new Node{3, new Node{5, new Node{6, new Node{8, new Node{9, NULL} } } } } };
    printList(in);
    split(in, odds, evens);
    printList(in);
    printList(odds);
    printList(evens);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply add `in= NULL;` after calling the function?

Comment: Do you mean `in = NULL;` after the function call in main?
If that is what you mean, it is not allowed. I have to submit only the split function. 
The main function is just something I created for testing.

Comment: Since the other lists already work, an easy workaround is to write a small wrapper function that does it.

Comment: What would that look like? I am trying to figure out something like that, but I am not entirely sure how to go about it. Since this is a head-recursive function.

Comment: Um... it's tail recursion function? Also it could have be more elegant by moving nodes from original list to result ones, nnobextra work of deletion reqiuired. Starting with the head pointer and zero-ing it, so caller would find it null.

Comment: OH! got it! thanks Swift:)

Comment: Tip: in C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may *move* Node to one or another list, by erasing pointer in original one:
Not a perfect but working solution (print added for illustration if you wan run it in your compiler to see how it works)

```
void split(Node*& in, Node*& odds, Node*& evens)
{
    Node* temp = in;
    if(!in) { 
           //std::cout << "\n"; 
           return;
    }
    in = nullptr;
    if(temp->value % 2 == 1) {
        //std::cout << "odd ";
        odds = temp;    
        return split( temp->next, odds->next, evens);
    } else {
        //std::cout << "even ";
        evens = temp;    
        return split( temp->next, odds, evens->next);
    }
}
```

It may have a non-growing footprint by using static (not a "stack") temporal:

```
static Node* temp;
temp = in;
```